# How can I get the characters between the second instance of a pair in Python?

Tags: python

If I have a string like this:

```
mystring = '[["not this one", "test string!"], ["or this one", ...'
```

How can I get the contents of the second pair? Preferably without using regex.

Comment: Is the `...` a literal `"..."` or does it mean you have more stuff? If the string is a valid Python expression, check out [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: It's a literal "...", it always breaks within 10-20 characters after the 4th parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to do it without a regex (often useful for performance in Python (and other languages), this should work (depending on the exact constraints on your string):

```
mystring.split('], ["')[1].split('",')[0]
```

That won't get you the *2nd* (or later) parts of the 2nd list, because they aren't in your string -- but it will get you `'or this one'`.

If you want to know how to make whatever program is **generating** the string stop leaving out the rest -- well, you'll need to actually mention what program it is (preferably in another question).

Also, please do accept an answer -- it's courteous.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how flexible your input is, regex is probably the way to go:

```
re.match(r'\[\[".*", ".*"\], \["(.*)", \.\.\.', mystring).group(1)
// 'or this one'
```

You'll have to tune it for variations in input, of course, e.g. if double quotes can sometimes be single quotes, or if there can be multiple spaces or no spaces after commas, etc.